# mysql_query returns only string type for int/fload db type

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to process a MySQL select result. My problem is that the sample code below only returns an Array containing all values as **string**-type even for columns that contain integers and floats.

```
$sth = mysql_query($selectstr);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_row($sth)) {
  foreach ($r as $value) echo gettype($value), "\n";
}
```

If I pass that array in `$r` to `json_encode(..)` I get JavaScript string values in the output (surrounded by quotes) and not unquoted number values (what i need).

How can I query the MySQL database and get a row-array containing the values with the correct type?

**Update**: Second parameter of `mysql_fetch_row(..)` removed. Originally I used `mysql_fetch_array(..)` which accepts the second parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the `mysql_fetch_*` functions are supposed to cast values according to their columns' types. For some, PHP doesn't even provide a matching internal data representation (think: `BIGINT`).

If you know the data-type of a query's result, you'll need to cast them manually. Otherwise [`mysql_field_type()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-type.php) would give you a hint on what type to convert the results to.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest folow code:

```
<?php
$sth = mysql_query($selectstr);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_row($sth,MYSQL_NUM)) {
  foreach ($r as $key => $value) 
  {
     if (is_numeric($value)) {
       $r[$key] = (float)$value;
     }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I think the check via `is_numeric()` can be omitted because the columns that contain number are known by the table schema.

Comment: BTW: `mysql_fetch_row()` [does not accept a second parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php).

Comment: @LinusKleen i just copied from auhtor post

Comment: @Robert i think cheaper to check via is_numeric that get meta data from database

Comment: @Ramil: Usually SQL queries are static, therefore you don't have to test for every row & field.

Comment: @Robert in this case you right. i suggest universal solution for dynamic fields

Answer (score 0):

In the end I changed my code as follows:

```
$sth = mysql_query($selectstr);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_row($sth)) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($r) ; $i++) 
    settype($r[$i],float); 
}
```

It assumes that all selected columns in the result set contain numeric values.