# trouble converting 2d php array to 2d javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have really done what I think is a not-code-review-passing hack to pass a 2-dimensional array from PHP to Javascript.  The outer array has elements, and each of its elements is an array.

Each inner array consists of 4 fields from my database records.  The inner array elements are: the name of a town, its latitude and its longitude, and an integer index.

Is the code working?  Yes.  But I'm hating the fact that I am 99% convinced that, as a fairly raw beginner, there is a much better way to create then pass a 2d array from PHP to Javascript and I need to know how, as I hacked this together through trial-and-error and reading lots of SO posts, and did not create this from a priori know-how, wisdom or confidence.

Each outer array element is an array that (needs to) look like this:

**top
array:**

**[0]** = ["Campbell", 37.21, 122.0, 0]

**[1]** = ["Sunnyvale", 37.54, 121.37, 1]

**[2]** = ["Saratoga", 37.24, 122.001, 2]

**[3]** = ......etc. etc...........

Note that the 2nd level arrays have a string, then a float, then another float, then an integer.

Here's the code in PHP that packages my database records into a 2-d PHP array (error checking, other code is not shown, for clarity):

```
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

 $outerArray = array();

 for($i = 0; $i < $numrows;  $i++)
 {
   $theRow = mysql_fetch_row($result);

   $city = $theRow[1];
   $lat = $theRow[22];
   $lng = $theRow[23];

   $outerArray[] = array($city, $lat, $lng, $i);
 }
 $latLngValues = json_encode($outerArray);

 // EDIT: ADDED TO TELL ME WHAT THIS 2d ARRAY ACTUALLY LOOKS LIKE
 var_dump($latLngValues);
```

In the **onload** handler for my web page, I call a javascript function and pass this array:

```
 <body onload='handleLoad(<?php echo $latLngValues ?>)'>
```

Here is my handleLoad():

```
 function handleLoad( latLng2dArray )
 {

   for (var i = 0; i < latLng2dArray.length; i++) 
   {

     var town = latLng2dArray[i];

     var latitude = Number(town[1]);
     var longitude = Number(town[2]);

     // I USE THE DATABASE RECORD'S NUMBERS TO CREATE A Gmaps LatLng
     var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

   }
```

There's probably a cleaner, and/or more efficient, way to do this.

For example, I found that if I did not use the **Number()** function to 'force' my database numbers into a number, the call to  "**new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)**"  was giving me ***NaN***.

So I'm hoping more experienced people can let me know a cleaner way.  While this code works, I hacked at it for a day through trial and error.

EDIT:  I used a var_dump() in my php code to see what the 2d array "$latLngValues" looks like just before it's passed to my onload handler, and "$latLngValues" looks like this:

```
  string(133) "[["Campbell","37.2724","-122",0],["Sunnyvale","37.2724","-122",1],["LosGatos","37.2607","-122",2],["Saratoga","37.2607","-122.046",3]]"
```

I want to point out this:  in my database, the data type I used is 'float' for the latitude and longitude.  Not sure how/why the var_dump shows them as a string (not floats) while the integer index is treated correctly, and not a string.

Comment: What does `$latLngValues` actually contain? Have you inspected it? Maybe when you do, the cause will be obvious.

Comment: @GolezTrol  okay, thanks for the suggestion, I added a call to var_dump in my Php code to tell me what latLngValues array looks like, and I added that to my post above.

Comment: All your numbers are strings. It somehow doesn't look right. Maybe you may consider casting `$lat` and `$lng` before adding them to the array?

Comment: @Alexander Okay thanks, I am not sure how to cast from string to float, in C it would just be putting (float) in front of the variable.  By the way, the 'float' data type is used in the database for the latitude and longitude, I don't know why the var_dump shows them as strings and yet var_dump shows the final array element -- an index value--  correctly as a number.

Comment: Looking at the documentation of [`mysql_fetch_row`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row), it seems to return all strings

Comment: @Alexander thanks, got that.  Well the code works.  I'm very doubtful after 1 day of hacking and trial-and-error the code I wrote is passable or penultimate.  It works but I hate slop as do most people, I'm hoping someone can explain a better or 'more commonly acceptable' way to create, pass and use a 2d PHP array in Javascript (aside from the mysql_fetch_row stringification issue, thanks to Alexander for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one offered a better coding strategy so for now, I'm going with the existing code above -- it aint pretty but it works.  I'll post back if a more-correct way is found.

Comment: There's no way around [`mysql_fetch_row` returning only strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852814/mysql-query-returns-only-string-type-for-int-fload-db-type). You need to cast numeric values as said above. I don't see a problem with `json_encode` though, that's fine